# How can an Apex test make a Visualforce request?

Tags: salesforce, apex

I have been reading "Understanding Testing in Apex".  In the section entitled Understanding Test Data, there is a sentence that reads

> If a test makes a Visualforce request, the executing test stays in the
>   test context but runs in a different thread, so test data isolation is
>   no longer enforced.

This is interesting and I would like to write a test class that illustrates this concept, but I am perplexed by the very first clause of the sentence:  "If a test makes a Visualforce request...".  How does one do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/testVFPage');
```

This is how request a vf request. Response of the resulting page will be store in 'pageRef'. [PageReference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_System_PageReference_ctor_2.htm) is used for this. The best practise to have a vf page rquest is as below.

```
PageReference pageRef = Page.testVFPage;
```

It allows the Force.com platform to detect the page dependancy.

If you need to do vf request for code coverage of your controller. Then do like this.

```
Test.setCurrentPageReference(Page.testPage);  //vf page request
ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id',ord.Id);  //pass parameters if needed
```